# Function to automatically change currency in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple currencies, I would like to find a manual function for the table below. What I want is the function to include all the possibilities I enter in column C and convert the price in column B into the equivalent price in column E. I might have up to 4-5 currencies I want the function to carry them all and convert according to the values in C,D.
Does that make sense?

[image]

Comment: Use a cell to choose the currency you want then get the result by using vlookup() to get the correct multiplier.

Comment: There is no such function in excel that is exactly what you want. Excel is not like google sheets which has API-connected functions such as =GOOGLETRANSLATE(). You will have to make a new column to record the exchange rate, and then do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)  Make an exchange rate table.  It can be on the same sheet or located else where.  You will need to update this table regularly to keep the exchange rates current.  You will also have to find a way to distinguish currencies from different countries that use the same name.  ie Peso. For this example I did the following:

[image]

I then built your table and automated the look up of the exchange rate in column E using the following formula:

```
 =VLOOKUP(D2,$N$3:$O$10,2,0)
```

For column F it was simply multiplying the local price with the exchange rate.

```
=C2*E2
```

Copy the above formulas down as needed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think I should have explained my final objective better.. What I would like to do is to have a function that also factors in the value in column D. 
I want to be able to type in "40" in a cell and excel to detect that the "currency" value is "AUD", "DIRHAM", "EUR" in the column next to it, and for it to multiply by the exchange rate according to that value. (IF D= AUD, multiply by "echange rate in cell X", IF D =DIRHAM, multiply by "echange rate in cell X", etc....).
The result would pop IN THE SAME CELL (the original cell in C). No F cells as above, ONLY C,D,E.  Is that possible?

Comment: ` =VLOOKUP(D2,$N$3:$O$10,2,0)*C2` is that what you want in E?